# upload image to database in mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using a fileupload control and uploading a image, now i want to save that image in to my database, how can we do that in mvc3?

got the below code from net, can we upload the image to database only with this piece of code, also what is ImageDB im not able to understand?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateImage(HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        Image newImage = new Image();
        newImage.MimeType = image.ContentType;

        var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(image.InputStream);
        newImage.Data = binaryReader.ReadBytes(image.ContentLength);
        binaryReader.Close();

        imageDB.Images.AddObject(newImage);
        imageDB.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: `imageDB` is a `DatabaseContext` from Entity Framework. How are you interacting with a database currently?

Comment: imageDB is not declared / initialized! What is the error message?

Comment: im using enterprise library not entity framework, how can i use enterprise library here?

Comment: i think i should write another method in model and call that method here after the line binaryReader.Close();?

Comment: Did you see any errors ? what has happend when you run above code ?